# How to prevent PHP from caching using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using following code for caching unknown as well as known files but I don't want PHP to be cached since it is causing problem with dynamic scripts. Note I don't want to add header to every PHP files to avoid it to be cached. Please suggest me if it is possible to prevent PHP from getting cached.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 year"
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Should work in both `.htaccess` and `httpd.conf`

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
 FileETag None
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset ETag
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
 Header set Pragma "no-cache"
 Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks it worked for me I just replaced customized it to

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
 FileETag None
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset ETag
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
 Header set Pragma "no-cache"
 Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```